# Error in accessing UID in Firebase Authentication Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I'm working on incorporating Firebase Authentication into my Xamarin app. The Firebase docs say that indicate that I can access a new user's UID in a completion method after they complete the CreateUser() method (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start). I have the following code in my IOS project within my Xamarin solution:

```
Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password, (AuthDataResult authResult, Foundation.NSError error) => {

    authResult.User.GetIdToken((string token, Foundation.NSError error1) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Token Is");
        Console.WriteLine(token);
    });

});
```

When the method fires, it says 'authResult' is Null. Specifically, the above method throws the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I access the user's UID?

Comment: If there is an error creating the user, `authResult.User` will be `null`.

Comment: Sure enough, when I write the 'error' to the console, something comes up! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an error creating the user, `authResult.User` will be `null`. So you'll need to check for that in your code:

```
Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password, (AuthDataResult authResult, Foundation.NSError error) => {
  if (error == null) {
    authResult.User.GetIdToken((string token, Foundation.NSError error1) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Token Is");
        Console.WriteLine(token);
    });
  }
});
```